# How to escape value keyword in mysql while using Select statement

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem while using Select statement where I have a column name as 'Value', and I want to retrieve the values based on the 'value' column with `SELECT` and `LIKE` operators.

Code:

```
 SELECT compo.clecompo
  FROM    compo compo
       ON (compo.clecompo = metadatas_compo.clecompo)
   AND ((metadatas_compo.value LIKE '%%NOM%%')
    OR (metadatas_values.metavalues_name LIKE '%%NOM%%'))
```

I highlighted the value keyword.. It's a sample of my query where i am not getting any results.
Note: `(metadatas_compo.value)` `metadatas_compo` is table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You escape literals in MySQL using backticks `

```
SELECT compo.clecompo FROM compo compo ON (compo.clecompo = metadatas_compo.clecompo) AND ((metadatas_compo.`value` LIKE '%%NOM%%') OR (metadatas_values.metavalues_name LIKE '%%NOM%%'))
```

However, it is advised to not use reserved literals in your table/column names. For a list of reserved words:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Hi @Gerry i modified the query with backticks..still its not working..any other help please

Comment: @rajasti277: `still its not working`! You are shown an error or an `Empty set`? If an error what is it?

Comment: Hi @Ravinder i am getting empty set, no results is being diaplayed

Comment: @rajasti277: `Empty Set` means, no syntax errors in your query now. If you still think that query should fetch some results, you may need to change your JOIN conditions.